# AngularJS dropdown-multiselect example not working

Tags: angularjs

I found [this example](http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/#/) of dropdown-multi-select.

I try to make code work in plunker:

```
**http://plnkr.co/edit/lKK6lAhczWNTgDRhPBsN?p=info**
```

but it not working.

Any idea what I am missing?Why I don't dropdown element on index.html page?

Comment: You are missing the code in this question entirely.  Wrapping a link inside formatting codes to circumvent the requirements of posting code with plunker links isn't appropriate, and will likely generate downvotes and/or close votes.

Comment: also, this looks suspiciously similar to another question you posted with code from this same source.  Did the answer you accepted there not solve the issue you are having?

Comment: After following the link to your plunker, It's clear what your problem is.  You are trying to use code written for Angular 1.x while trying to actually load Angular 2 Beta.  Angular 1 and Angular 2 ***are not the same***, and code is not interchangeable between them.

Comment: @Claies there were lots mistake in his plunkr, that was not working in any sense.. like he just copy pasted the things from the ng-dropdown site

Comment: @PankajParkar yes, and similar issues in the previous question regarding the same exact code snippet.  It's clear that there is a fundamental misunderstanding of Angular in general here.

Comment: @Claies he just not even tried to learn how could atleast make plunkr runnable

Comment: @Claies Anyways I made it workable.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You made a lots mistake over there, Actually the mistakes are more than what I mentioned below.

1. `ng-app="sensorManagement"` has been missed
2. You were added Angular2 reference instead of angular `1.x`
3. angular.module('sensorManagement',[]) has not been created
4. `ng-controller` with `controllerAs` is missing on the page.
5. Bootstrap styling is missed to add on the page
6. Script reference to `controller.js` & `directive.js` were missing

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/BVCg8ifCFCyiDenVBn2C?p=preview)

Comment: thanks for help.But there is bug in your plunker,Please check it

Comment: @Michael what is the problem?

Comment: when item unchecked it disappears

Comment: @Michael I opened one github issue for the same https://github.com/dotansimha/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/issues/136